# Could someone with Python expertise check this code please?

Tags: python

When I run [this](http://gunslingerc0de.wordpress.com/2010/06/04/381/) prog it doesn't run for some reason. The author's notes at the top of the code on the link provided show example output, like for example "encode/decode" doesn't appear in place of `%sencode%s` / `%sdecode%s`, so not sure what the problem is.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import binascii, sys, time

RED = '\033[31m'
WHITE = '\033[37m'
RESET = '\033[0;0m'

def main():
  print "shellcode hex encode decoder"
  print "programmer : gunslinger_ <yudha.gunslinger[at]gmail.com>"
  print "what do you want to do ? %sencode%s / %sdecode%s" % (RED, RESET, WHITE, RESET)
  q = raw_input("=> ")

if q == "encode": 
    inputtype = raw_input("Please input data : ")
    print "shellcode => ",
    for encoded in inputtype:
        print "\b\\x"+encoded.encode("hex"),
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print RESET

elif q == "decode":
    inputtype = raw_input("Please input data : ")
    cleaninput = inputtype.replace("\\x","")
    print "hex       => ",cleaninput
    print "plaintext => ",
    print "\b"+cleaninput.decode("hex")

else:
    print "wrong answer ! your choice is %sencode%s or %sdecode%s" % (RED, RESET, WHITE, RESET)
    sys.exit(1)   


if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Comment: One obvious problem is the broken indentation. You'll have to get that fixed before doing anything else.

Comment: "it doesn't run for some reason". Do you get an error? Which one? Please post the full error message.

Comment: No I fixed the indentation on the program, but its hard to do the indentation on this site for me.  It doesn't cause any errors at first, it says "what do you want to do ? %sencode%s / %sdecode%s" but it is supposed to say ""what do you want to do ? encode / decode" according to the notes on the file if you look at the link.  Also then after, if I put in some shell code to decode: \x45R\126\105\, it says:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\test.py", line 36, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python27\test.py", line 28, in main
    print "\b"+cleaninput.decode("hex")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\hex_codec.py", line 42, in hex_decode
    output = binascii.a2b_hex(input)
TypeError: Non-hexadecimal digit fou

Comment: @user1088793: Just a tip, if you want to indent more than one line at the same time select those lines and use `Ctrl+K`. *Try it beacuse your indentation is still off.*

Comment: The escape codes for adding coloured output to the console only work for Unix like terminals. Are you using windows? It works for me with Cygwin bash shell, as this is a *nix terminal for windows.

Comment: Please move this to code review.stackexchange.com

Comment: What did you input for `raw_input("Please input data : ")` ? If you change to `print "hex       => ",repr(cleaninput)` do you see any non hex digits inside the quote characters ? For example extraneous whitespace ?

Answer (score 1):

Whitespace is important in Python.

Here's the code with indentation corrected:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import binascii, sys, time

RED = '\033[31m'
WHITE = '\033[37m'
RESET = '\033[0;0m'

def main():
    print "shellcode hex encode decoder"
    print "programmer : gunslinger_ <yudha.gunslinger[at]gmail.com>"
    print "what do you want to do ? %sencode%s / %sdecode%s" % (RED, RESET, WHITE, RESET)
    q = raw_input("=> ")

    if q == "encode": 
        inputtype = raw_input("Please input data : ")
        print "shellcode => ",
        for encoded in inputtype:
            print "\b\\x"+encoded.encode("hex"),
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print RESET
    elif q == "decode":
        inputtype = raw_input("Please input data : ")
        cleaninput = inputtype.replace("\\x","")
        print "hex       => ",cleaninput
        print "plaintext => ",
        print "\b"+cleaninput.decode("hex")
    else:
        print "wrong answer ! your choice is %sencode%s or %sdecode%s" % (RED, RESET, WHITE, RESET)
        sys.exit(1)   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The linked file indentation is all right, I guess that was just an OP editing problem.

Answer (score 1):

This program is using console escape sequences to set colours - this is an operating-specific thing, and will depend on the shell you're using.

A quick fix is to redefine the constants at the top, like this:

```
RED = '"'
WHITE = '"'
RESET = '"'
```

then it will say:

```
your choice is "encode" or "decode"
```